# Why are group permissions different when using mkdir and mkdir -p?

Tags: ubuntu, file-permissions, access-control-list

I'm trying to make new files and directories within a directory always have the same permissions and group.

I've done this:

```
cd /
sudo mkdir apps
sudo chown deploy:www-data apps
sudo chmod g+s apps
sudo setfacl -d -m g:www-data:rwx apps/
cd apps
mkdir foo
ls -lah foo
```

I get the correct permissions and group ownership for foo:

```
drwxrwsr-x+  2 deploy www-data 4.0K Apr 22 17:29 foo
```

However, if I do this:

```
mkdir -p /apps/bar
```

... I get the correct group ownership, but not the group permissions:

```
drwxr-sr-x+  2 deploy www-data 4.0K Apr 22 17:30 bar
```

There is clearly something I do not understand in the way ACLs work. I can't find why the second directory does not have rwx group permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The `mkdir -p` will use the default umask.
You can combine it with `-m` to set the permissions

```
mkdir -m 2775 -p path/dirname
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I noticed. How can I make mkdir respect the ACLs ?